# How to show/hide loading wheel with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have buttons on my site that load new content via ajax. I made a div to house a loading wheel for while the content is loading.  On the button click function, I have it first add a class to the div to make the loading wheel appear, then load the data, then remove the loading wheel class.  This doesn't seem to work. I don't see the loading wheel at all. I even tried making the js execution pause for a second before the loading wheel is removed, but i still don't see it.  See the jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/g8np7qLa/

JS:

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function show_loader(){
    $("#loader").addClass("loader");
event.preventDefault();
}


function hide_loader(){
    $("#loader").removeClass("loader");
event.preventDefault();
}

if($(".item-button").length) {


    $(".item-button").click(function(event) {
        show_loader();

    //load the ajax data
 wait(1000);
 hide_loader();

event.preventDefault();

    });


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use `setTimeout`

```
$(".item-button").click(function(event) {
    show_loader();
    //load the ajax data
    //wait(1000);
    setTimeout(hide_loader, 1000);
    //hide_loader();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's the working example

```js
function show_loader(){
 $("#loader").addClass("loader");
  //event.preventDefault();
}

function hide_loader(){
 $("#loader").removeClass("loader");
  //event.preventDefault();
}

if($(".item-button").length) {
 $(".item-button").click(function(event) {
  show_loader();
   //load the ajax data
    //wait(1000);
    setTimeout(hide_loader, 1000);
    //hide_loader();
    event.preventDefault();
 });
}
```

```css
.loader{
 position:fixed; top:0;
 left:0; right:0; bottom:0;     
 background:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
 /*padding-top:150px;*/
 padding-top:20px;
 z-index:99999;
}

.loader div{
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="item-button" data-item-name="itemname">
click here
</a>
```